# How to debug PySpark's Scala execution?

Tags: python, scala, debugging, pyspark

I'm able to run the remote debugger in IntelliJ Idea and connect it to my SparkSession. However, upon setting breakpoints on Scala code (ex: I set one on 'DataFrameReader.format(string)', it does not stop at the breakpoint when I run python code from my pyspark session. How can I make that happen?